# Descobrir o Hostname do Usuário

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação Rodando com AngularJS onde preciso saber o nome da máquina (do usuário) que está acessando a aplicação. Alguém já precisou fazer isso com javascript?

> Obs.: O front-end está fora da minha rede local

Comment: Acredito que por motivos de segurança Javascript não tem permissão de obter acesso ao disco e/ou ao sistema do cliente.

Comment: Pois é @Lucas Costa, acho que vou ter que bolar outra forma. Quando o front-end estava na minha rede local eu conseguia pegar o nome de boa, mas agora que está na AWS não está mais funcionando.

Comment: Você vai precisar usar alguma tecnologia de back-end, como node.js ou Java, como alternativas pra essa sua missão :P

Comment: Aham, já uso Spring no backend.

Comment: @Danilo Silva pode mostrar como pegar no nome do hostname da máquina do utilizador dentro de uma rede local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Não é possível.

**Versão longa**: Por razões de segurança (isolamento de ambiente), nenhum dos objetos fornecidos por implementações atuais de ECMAScript incluem informações do ambiente em si - apenas aquelas herdadas historicamente, como versão do OS e plataforma (via [window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator)).

Tecnologias como DNS reverso podem ser utilizadas se o servidor recebendo a conexão possuir uma conexão direta com o cliente (sem gateways, VPNs ou NATs intermediários, por exemplo).